# Angular- xeditable with ui select inside Form element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select, angular-xeditable

I want [editable-ui-select](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#uiselect) inside form tag. But it is not working inside form element.

Here is my code

```
 <form class="col-xs-12 form-horizontal" 
                 editable-form role="form" name="uiTest">
     <div ng-click="uiTest.$show()"  onaftersave="ctrl.onTypeSelect(ctrl.selectedType)"  
                      editable-ui-select="ctrl.selectedType" 
                      buttons="no" 
                      e-clickable="true" 
                      blur="submit"
                      data-e-name="type" 
                      name="type" 
                      theme="bootstrap"
                      data-e-ng-model="ctrl.selectedType" >
            
                                        {{ctrl.selectedType.key}}
                                      
          <editable-ui-select-match allow-clear="true" placeholder="Search {{ctrl.label}} by Name">
                                            {{$select.selected.name}} 
          </editable-ui-select-match>
          <editable-ui-select-choices repeat="item in ctrl.filteredItems = (ctrl.types | filter : {name : $select.search})">
                                            <div ng-bind-html="item.name | highlight: $select.search"></div> 
          </editable-ui-select-choices>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I want it without the use of buttons. So I have added `buttons="no"`. When I run this, the ui-select opens, i can select item from drop down, but on select of item, it doesn't changes back to view mode.

### EDITED

I have added a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d0pu5s7x/2/) link.

Comment: working Plunker/Fiddler link please.

Comment: @VipinKumar working fiddle added

Comment: The fiddler link is different from question's content. Can u please try to explain what do you want?

Comment: @VipinKumar I have updated the fiddle as per my need. I dont need buttons. So I have hidden them.

Comment: you can use `<form  blur="submit"`. let me if this works for you.